# How can I change the CSS file's font and colors in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, fonts

Visual Studio 2010 shows CSS files with no color. The CSS property names, CSS value names and everything else are all black.

I tried this: Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors. Visual Studio processes the CSS file as plain text. 
How can I fix this?

[image: Picture showing CSS file loaded as Plain Text]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your stylesheet to your project.
right  click the css file and select include in project
:)